# Serie fibonacci en una matriz n*n, C#

Tags: c#

como puedo introducir la serie fibonacci en un matriz "N" por "N" ejemplo:

```
1 1 2 3
5 . . .
```

Mi resultado no es el esperado, no muestra las serie en la matriz.

Este es mi codigo:

```
int i, j, n,aux;
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] matriz1 = new int[n, n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;  j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                matriz1[i, j] = j + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                {
                    aux = a;
                    a = b;
                    b = aux + a;
                    Console.Write(" "+a);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(matriz1[i, j] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
     Console.Read();
```

EL resultado que sale en pantalla es:
1 1 2 3 5 8........
0  0
0  0
0  0

Comment: Hola Rom, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Por favor, vuelve a leer el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Aqui se busca el ayudar a resolver un problema que el usuario ha trabajado previamente. Mostrando el proceso que ha seguido desde investigacion , implementacion y pruebas. Trata de hacerlo tú y si tienes errores o problemas preguntarlo aqui. Así como está es de baja calidad, muy amplia. Un saludo

Comment: Has intentado algo? Si es asi, por favor pega el código en tu pregunta pulsando en [edit]

Comment: Y por qué no es el resultado esperado? Por favor **detalla** qué sucede....

Comment: Hola Rom, tengo una respuesta esperando para ti. Pero como bien dice @lois6b, en [es.so] pedimos que las preguntas demuestren un esfuerzo en haber sido solucionadas, que se ponga el código que sea relevante para la pregunta y que, si éste no funciona, se explique que es lo que se ha detectado como solución errónea. Edita tu pregunta explicando por encima que resultado estas obteniendo y porque no es el correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo tienes que tener en cuenta el algoritmo de fibonacci, que este se puede resolver de manera [recursiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n) y también por medio de [iteraciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteraci%C3%B3n), que en tu caso, como veo, haces [el algoritmo fibonacci por iteración](http://jesquivelm.blogspot.com/2013/09/serie-de-fibonacci-super-simple-en-c.html).

Aquí te dejo el código y también te dejo el ejemplo [corriendo](http://ideone.com/BsEoT7).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, i, j, n, aux, b, m;
            a = 0;
            b = 1;
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            m = n;
            n *= n; //como ocupas llenar una matriz cuadrada, ocupas que fibonacci llene n*n campos.
            int[,] mat = new int[m, m];
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    aux = a;
                    a = b; //intercambio valores
                    b = aux + a; //cailculo el nuevo valor
                    mat[i, j] = a;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(mat[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La sucesión de fibonacci se basa en sumar los dos numeros anteriores al que vamos a calcular. Hay muchas formas de solucionarlo, pero me voy a basar en tu código para darte una posible solucion.Básicamente, se trata de almacenar los dos numeros anteriores para calcular el siguiente, y una vez calculado, se almacena el anterior como el "segundo anterior" y el recién calculado como anterior:

```
int i, j, n;
int ant1 = 1; //para el numero anterior
int ant2 = 0; //para el numero anterior al anterior
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] matriz1 = new int[n, n];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (i == j & i == 0) //Cuando es el primer elemento de la serie, le ponemos 0
        {
            matriz1[i, j] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            matriz1[i, j] = ant1 + ant2; //en los demas casos,sumamos los dos numeros anteriores
        }
        ant2 = ant1;          //pasamos el numero anterior al segundo anterior
        ant1 = matriz1[i, j]; // y almacenamos el numero recién calculado como el anterior
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matriz1[i, j] + "\t"); //mostramos los números de la fila
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); //retorno de carro para mostrar la fila siguiente
}
Console.Read();
```